# how to generate coverage.xml in jmockit?

Tags: java, jmockit

I am using Jmockit for my unit tests and I have also included jmockit-coverage.jar in my classpath. Currently it generates the following files under 'coverage-reports' folder:coverage.css,coverage.js,index.html,logo.png,prettify.js

But its not generating coverage.xml. According to the document here - http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r289/trunk/www/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html, I think I need to add 'jmockit-coverage-xmlfull.jar' in my class path. But I am not able to find that jar online. Its not available in jmockit download link.

Could you please let me know how to fix this issue?

Thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link seems to be an older one showing an older svn revision number `(r289)`. The latest one lies here 
  http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/www/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html#output.
 Looks like it supports html as of now, but could not find xml. Basically the `jmockit-coverage-output` property is used to decide the output.

If you really need the xml version, you might need to download an older version which has all the jars. Try this link.

https://jmockit.googlecode.com/files/jmockit-0.993.zip

Comment: A `coverage.ser` file can be generated now, when external processing is desired.